# How do i search query from multiple firebase collection? / how to add multiple firebase collection in one stream builder?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:e_shop_app/model/item.dart';
import 'package:e_shop_app/screens/appbar_for_search.dart';
import 'package:e_shop_app/widgets/colors.dart';
import 'package:e_shop_app/widgets/user_home_product_card_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchProductScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchProductScreenState createState() => _SearchProductScreenState();
}

class _SearchProductScreenState extends State<SearchProductScreen> {
  late Future<QuerySnapshot> docList;
  String query = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarForsearch(
        bottom: PreferredSize(
            child: searchWidget(), preferredSize: const Size(47.0, 47.0)),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: (query != "")
            ? FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("items") // i want to add multiple collections here so i can search data from multiple firebase collections
                .where("caseSearch", arrayContains: query.toLowerCase())
                .snapshots()
            : FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("items")
                .orderBy("publishedDate", descending: true)
                .snapshots(),
        builder: (ctx, snap) {
          return (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
              ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    itemCount: snap.data!.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      ItemModel model = ItemModel.fromJson(
                          snap.data!.docs[index].data()!
                              as Map<String, dynamic>);

                      return UserHomeProductCardWidget(
                          itemModel: model,
                          context: context,
                          productId: snap.data!.docs[index].id);
                    },
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget searchWidget() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 55.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            offset: const Offset(0, 10),
            blurRadius: 50,
            color: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.23),
          ),
        ],
        gradient: const LinearGradient(
          colors: [kPrimaryColor, Colors.green],
          begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
          end: FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
          stops: [0.0, 1.0],
          tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 45.0,
        height: 40.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: kBackgroundColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.5),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      query = value;
                    });
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                    hintText: "Search here...",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.5)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to add multiple firebase collections to search data from. how to add multiple firebase collection in one query. my goal is search data from all the collections and display result.
I want to add multiple firebase collections to search data from. how to add multiple firebase collection in one query. my goal is search data from all the collections and display result.
I want to add multiple firebase collections to search data from. how to add multiple firebase collection in one query. my goal is search data from all the collections and display result.

Comment: Instead of adding the same text multiple times to work around a message that Stack Overflow gives about the text to code ratio, heed the message and add more meaningful information to your question. For example: **what** are the collections you want to read from? How is the code you shared relevant to the problem, i..e which line isn't doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: any collection, for example, you can use collection_one, collection_two, collection_three. from those all three collection i want to display casesearch query ( .where("caseSearch", arrayContains: query.toLowerCase()) ) from all three collection in one bulilder.

Comment: there is a library all multi_query_firestore on pub dev. but that is not supporting new version of dart.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/multi_query_firestore

Comment: MultiQuery(
    list: [
      ref.collection('A').where('count', isGreaterThan: 2),
      ref.collection('B').where('size', isEqualTo: 5),
      ref.collection('C').where('age', isLessThanOrEqualTo: 3)
    ]
).snapshots()

Comment: All of these are good edits to your original question, so I recommend making them there and provide this type of information right away going forward.

Comment: There is no way to read from multiple collections in the way you want with a single read operation in Firestore. You will have to perform a separate read for each collection, and then merge the results in your application code. --- If a library that does that hasn't been updated for your version, consider updating it yourself.